# Getting a "cannot convert" error when trying to used a cached token

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm getting the following error when trying to use a cached token. I'm using the list that was provided as an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.IAccount'`

```
        static async Task<GraphServiceClient> Auth()
        {

            var clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"]).Build();
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string token = null;
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"]).Build();
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts)
                       .ExecuteAsync();
                token = result.AccessToken;

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                            async (requestMessage) =>
                            {
                                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                            }));
            return graphClient;
        }
```

Comment: Well, an `IEnumerable` is something with which you traverse a collection, and `IAccount` is a single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call that is causing the error is this one

```
result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts)
                  .ExecuteAsync();
```

`AcquireTokenSilent` requires two variables, `IEnumerable<String>` (scops) and `string` (loginHint). What you are passing for `loginHist` is an array of accounts when it's supposed to be a single string (single account).

```
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
```

[GetAccountsAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.clientapplicationbase.getaccountsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_ClientApplicationBase_GetAccountsAsync)'s return type is `IEnumerable` which is why its throwing the error at that call.

In an [example here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web/TokenAcquisition.cs), the account looked up is from the list.

```
// Get the account
IAccount account = await application.GetAccountAsync(accountIdentifier).ConfigureAwait(false);

// Special case for guest users as the Guest oid / tenant id are not surfaced.
if (account == null)
{
    if (loginHint == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loginHint));

    var accounts = await application.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    account = accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Username == loginHint);
}
```

Add this line to your code:

```
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
IAccount account = accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Username == loginHint); // <--- Get Account from accounts
result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account) // Use account instead of accounts.
                  .ExecuteAsync();
token = result.AccessToken;
```

Comment: make sure you add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yep, just noticed that. I'm now getting `The name 'loginHint' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: LoginHint is supposed to be a string variable.. a username you are working with. Do check the link i sent that has a full code on how to do what you are trying to do